# AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'IntType'

Tags: python, pydev

I'm trying to use the AGW (Advance Generics Widgets) library and have downloaded the source code for the library and their demos and am getting errors. For example in [`ultimatelistctrl.py`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.html#module-wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl), on the INTEGER_TYPES line below::

```
import types # a compiled extension
INTEGER_TYPES = [types.IntType, types.LongType]
```

I get this error:

> AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'IntType'

C:\Python35\Lib is on the PyDev - PYTHONPATH
If I go to  C:\Python35\Lib\types.py, I do not see `IntType` or `LongType`
A previous answer on SO suggests adding the module (`types` in this case) to the `forced builtins`, which I did to no effect.

What is the problem?

Comment: What version of Python do you use ?

Comment: Looks like it disappeared in Python 3. [Python 2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html) vs [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/types.html)

Comment: And which Phoenix version ? Current one refers to [`six.integer_types`](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/wx/lib/agw/ultimatelistctrl.py#L557)

Comment: @roganjosh: You are correct. Looking at the project page now, it looks like AGW was lasted updated. in March 2012.l guess this is a dead project.

Comment: I can't find the source code to the library so I have no idea how much work it would be to get it up and running in Python 3. Other than that, I don't think more can be said than that duplicate sorry.

Comment: The source is on [Subversion](http://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxPython/3rdParty/AGW/) but don't bother with Python 3. With the volume of errors I see and the aforementioned lack of activity, I think its best to look elsewhere.

Comment: AFAIK the source code is on GitHub: https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix . AGW module is under wx/lib/agw (see https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.lib.agw.html#module-wx.lib.agw) Phoenix is compatible with Python3

Comment: Ok, Phoenix is a rewrite of the original wx project, but it seems maintained, so maybe a good alternative to check